# Why does astro render the children of a custom element outside of the element?

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs

I tried using customElements.define with the Framework Astro. I Managed to create the custom Element, but the ordering of my elements isnt mirrored in the DOM as it is in Astro. Actually im not sure if Astro is doing something behind the scenes or if its just my lacking knowledge about custom defined elements in HTML.

Basically I have a Table looking like

```
<table>
    ...
    <tbody>
        srcs.map((src, i) => {
             <SingleVideo src={src} .../>
        })
    </tbody>
</table>
```

where SingleVideo is the imported single-video.

It contains the custom element and looks like

```
<single-video
    data-name={name}
    data-amount={amount}>
    <th>{name}</th>
    <th id="imageLoad">asd</th>
    <th id="imageLoadAverage">asd</th>
    <th id="componentLoad">asd</th>
    <th id="componentLoadAverage">asd</th>
    <th id="failure">asd</th>

    <th>
        {
            [...Array(amount)].map((item, i) => (
                <video
                    hidden
                    id={"video" + i + name}>
                    <source
                        src={src}
                        type="video/webm"
                    />
                </video>
            ))
        }
    </th>
</single-video>
    
    
    
    class MeasuringVideo extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
    
            const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
            shadow.innerHTML = `<slot></slot>`
    
            //Contains Logic, f.e:
            const imageLoad = this.querySelector("#imageLoad");
            //imageLoad is null
    
    
        }
    }
    
    customElements.define("single-video", MeasuringVideo);
    console.log(document.querySelector("single-video"));
</script>
```

In the end it looks like

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dXx2.png)

Comment: The `<single-video>` tag needs a closing tag `</single-video>`

Comment: ah damn, i messed up the code fragment in the question. Ill update it.

Comment: I have seen a similar issue before when using `<table>` elements: https://github.com/withastro/compiler/issues/725 It may be a bug

Comment: Also, I think you may need `<tr>` elements inside your table

Comment: Yep, i need the tr, i guess i removed it to test if i could replace it with my custom element and didnt put it back in. If this is a bug, can you think of some kind of workaround?